# Dialogflow - sending media from python flask app to twilio

Tags: python, twilio, dialogflow-es

I am trying to figure out whether it is possible to send a response back to the user from my python flask app to twilio, which is integrated with dialogflow.

Using Twilio and python only, and using messaging response I can send images back to the user.

However, once I link the integration with dialogflow, I'm not sure what to pass back to dialogflow for it to recognise the image link.

Currently I am using fulfillment text to send text from python to Twilio/dialogflow.

Please help.

Comment: Are you using this [Google Dialogflow provided Twilio integration](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dialogflow-integrations/tree/master/twilio)? If so, it [only supports text out of the box](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dialogflow-integrations/blob/master/twilio/server.js#L50-L53). You may need to update it yourself if you want to respond with images too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your reply. I have managed to solve this issue. For others experiencing a similar issue, using Client.messages.create function, it allows you to attach a file, using the mediaUrl parameter.